# fast swiping gives wrong position while sharing Images but it works when I swipe slowly in ViewPager(weird)

Tags: android, android-viewpager

This is an gallery app example in which I am retrieving images from server and showing it on ViewPager by using Glide and there is also share and download feature on ViewPager. Everything is working perfectly fine when I swipe Images slowly but when I swipe Images continuously fast it gives wrong image position when I try to share and download Image. Need some advice to solve this issue Thank you in Advance.

Activity:

```
public class SlideActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String URL = "API";

    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private Context context = SlideActivity.this;
    private ViewPagerAdapter adapter;
    private int position;
    private List<Trending> data;
    private ImageView shareIcon, shareImage, downloadImage;


    @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.slide_activity);


            viewPager = findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
            final ProgressBar progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progress);
            shareIcon = findViewById(R.id.shareviewpager);
            downloadImage = findViewById(R.id.iv_download_slide);

            //final String fileName = getIntent().getStringExtra("filename");
            position = getIntent().getIntExtra("pos", 0);

            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            StringRequest request = new StringRequest(URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
                    Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();
                    TrendingData users = gson.fromJson(response, SlideData.class);
                    data = users.getData();
                    adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(context, data);
                    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
                    viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(1);
                    viewPager.setCurrentItem(position);
                    if (position == 0) {
                        pageSelected(0);
                    }
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    Toast.makeText(SlideActivity.this, "Oops Something Went Wrong. Please try again later..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

            RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
            queue.add(request);
            viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPageScrolled(int i, float v, int i1) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onPageSelected(int i) {
                    pageSelected(i);
                }

                @Override
                public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int i) {

                }
            });


    }

    //separate Thread for sharing Images
    private static class LoadImage extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Drawable> {

        private WeakReference<TrendingSlideActivity> activityWeakReference;

        LoadImage(SlideActivity context) {
            activityWeakReference = new WeakReference<>(context);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected Drawable doInBackground(String... strings) {

            Bitmap bmp = null;
            HttpURLConnection connection = null;
            try {
                connection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(strings[0]).openConnection();
                connection.connect();
                InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
                //bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);

                BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                options.inPurgeable = true;
                options.outHeight = 50;
                options.outWidth = 50;
                String imageType = options.outMimeType;
                options.inSampleSize = 4;
                //options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.RGB_565;
                bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input, null, options);

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }finally {
                assert connection != null;
                connection.disconnect();
            }
            return new BitmapDrawable(bmp);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Drawable result) {

            SlideActivity activity = activityWeakReference.get();
            if (activity == null) return;

            activity.shareImage = new ImageView(activity);
            //Add image to ImageView
            activity.shareImage.setImageDrawable(result);

        }

    }


    //share function
    public void onShareItem(View v) {
        // Get access to bitmap image from view
        // Get access to the URI for the bitmap
        if (v != null) {
            Uri bmpUri = getLocalBitmapUri((ImageView) v);
            if (bmpUri != null) {
                // Construct a ShareIntent  with link to image
                Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
                shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, bmpUri);
                shareIntent.setType("image/*");
                // Launch sharing dialog for image
                context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share Data"));
            } else {
                // ...sharing failed, handle error
            }
        }else {
            Toast.makeText(SlideActivity.this,"Please Wait Image is Loading...",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    //converting imageView into Bitmap
    public Uri getLocalBitmapUri(ImageView imageView) {
        // Extract Bitmap from ImageView drawable
        Drawable drawable = imageView.getDrawable();
        Bitmap bmp;
        if (drawable instanceof BitmapDrawable) {
            bmp = ((BitmapDrawable) imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
        } else {
            return null;
        }
        // Store image to default external storage directory
        Uri bmpUri = null;
        try {
            // Use methods on Context to access package-specific directories on external storage.
            // This way, you don't need to request external read/write permission.
            File file = new File(context.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "share_image_" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".png");
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
            bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, out);
            out.close();
            // **Warning:** This will fail for API >= 24, use a FileProvider as shown below instead.
            bmpUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return bmpUri;
    }

    //checking storage permission
    public boolean isStoragePermissionGranted() {
        String TAG = "Storage Permission";
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
            if (this.checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                    == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Permission is granted");
                return true;
            } else {
                Log.i(TAG, "Permission is revoked");
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);
                return false;
            }
        } else { //permission is automatically granted on sdk<23 upon installation
            Log.i(TAG, "Permission is granted");
            return true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                           String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case 1: {

                // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
                if (grantResults.length > 0
                        && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                    // permission was granted, yay! Do the
                    // contacts-related task you need to do.
                } else {

                    // permission denied, boo! Disable the
                    // functionality that depends on this permission.
                    AlertDialog alertDialog =
                            new AlertDialog.Builder(SlideActivity.this)
                                    .setTitle("Required Storage Permission")
                                    .setMessage("You have disabled the permission permanently,\n" +
                                            "To enable the permissions press Yes you will be navigated to Settings screen")
                                    .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                            Intent intent = new Intent();
                                            intent.setAction(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
                                            Uri uri = Uri.fromParts("package", getPackageName(), null);
                                            intent.setData(uri);
                                            startActivity(intent);
                                            dialog.cancel();
                                        }
                                    })
                                    .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                            //  Action for 'NO' Button
                                            dialog.cancel();
                                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"This Permission is Required to Download & Share Images.",
                                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        }
                                    }).show();
                    alertDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
                }
                return;
            }

            // other 'case' lines to check for other
            // permissions this app might request
        }
    }
    //Saving Image to SD Card
    public void saveImageToGallery(ImageView iv) {
//        //to get the image from the ImageView (say iv)
//        BitmapDrawable draw = (BitmapDrawable) iv.getDrawable();
//        Bitmap bitmap = draw.getBitmap();
        if (iv != null) {
            Drawable drawable = iv.getDrawable();

            Bitmap bmp = null;
            if (drawable instanceof BitmapDrawable) {
                bmp = ((BitmapDrawable) iv.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
            } else {
            }

            FileOutputStream outStream = null;

            String sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
            if (isStoragePermissionGranted()) {
                File dir = new File(sdCard, "/GalleryApp");
                if (!dir.exists()) {
                    boolean mkdirs = dir.mkdirs();
                }

                try {
                    String fileName = String.format(Locale.getDefault(),"%d.jpg", System.currentTimeMillis());
                    File outFile = new File(dir, fileName);

                    outStream = new FileOutputStream(outFile);
                    assert bmp != null;
                    bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, outStream);
                    outStream.flush();
                    outStream.close();
                    Toast.makeText(SlideActivity.this, "Image Saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Log.i("TAAAAAAAAAAAAG", "onPictureTaken - wrote to " + outFile.getAbsolutePath());

                    String filePath = outFile.getPath();

                    MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(this,
                            new String[]{filePath}, null,
                            new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {
                                public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
                                    Log.i("ExternalStorage", "Scanned " + path + ":");
                                    Log.i("ExternalStorage", "-> uri=" + uri);
                                }
                            });
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(SlideActivity.this, "Please Wait Image is Loading...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    public void pageSelected(int position) {
        //currentImage = viewPager.getCurrentItem();
        //Log.i("TAG", "page selected " + currentImage);

        final String fileName1 = data.get(position).getFileName();

        final String url2 = "API" + fileName1;

        new LoadImage(TrendingSlideActivity.this).execute(url2);
        shareIcon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (isStoragePermissionGranted()) {
                    onShareItem(shareImage);
                }
            }
        });

        downloadImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                saveImageToGallery(shareImage);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

ViewPagerAdapter

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
    private static final String URL = "API";

    private Context context;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private ImageView wallpaper;
    private List<Trending> data;
    View view;
    String url;
    ViewPager viewPager;

    public ViewPagerAdapter() {
    }

    public ViewPagerAdapter(Context context, List<Trending> data) {
        this.context = context;
        this.data = data;
    }

    @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(@NonNull final ViewGroup container,int position) {

        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(container.getContext());
        final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.trending_viewpager_item_layout, container, false);
        viewPager = view.findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
        wallpaper = view.findViewById(R.id.walpaperImage);
        final String fileName1 = data.get(position).getFileName();
        //final String id = data.get(position).getId();

        url = URL + fileName1;
        Glide.with(context).load(url).diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL).into(wallpaper);
        container.addView(view,0);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(@NonNull View view, @NonNull Object o) {
        return view.equals(o);
    }
    @Override
    public void destroyItem(@NonNull ViewGroup container, int position, @NonNull Object object) {
        container.removeView((View) object);

    }

}
```